# How would I convert this to a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq

wondering if anyone can help.  This works, but I was wondering how it would look in Lambda instead (Just curious !)

Codes is simply an array of id's and each item has a code...

```
        var qry = from i in items
                where Codes.Contains(i.Code)
                select i;

        return qry.ToList();
```

Thanks
Andrew.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
return items.Where(i => Codes.Contains(i.Code)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var qry = items.Where(i => Codes.Contains(i.Code));
```

Answer (score 0):

If items is a `List<Item>`, you can save yourself the `ToList()` call like so:

```
var qry = items.FindAll(i => Codes.Contains(i.Code));
```